# deleting rows based on a column's value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col.1 : a a a a a b b b c c c
col.2 : 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

I want to drop all values for a similar value in col.1 after 1 is encountered in col.2. The result should be like:

```
col.1 : a a a b b c c c
col.2 : 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Is there any way to do it fast in pandas? Currently I'm using numpy where and it seems to be very slow.

Comment: Can you explain the metric a little better, please?

Comment: Im dropping rows. which metric are you talking about?

Comment: What is the purpose here? Do you want to count what element contains the 1? I simply think you have simplified a problem to the point where there may be a more obvious way to solve it, if you would tell us more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['col.2'] = df.groupby('col.1')['col.2'].cumsum()
df['col.2'] = df.groupby('col.1')['col.2'].cumsum()
df = df[df['col.2']<2]
```